# How to check if a nsdictionary key has values or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code

```
 for(NSDictionary* key in [Tags valueForKey:@"data"]) {
                if ([[key valueForKey:@"hashtag"] rangeOfString:self.searchKey options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
                    NSLog(@"found key");
}
break;
}
```

For nsdictionary

[image]

I do not want to use a for loop to check the first key value if it exists or not. Actually i just want to check if there are hashtags returned in the dictionary or not using only if statement . How is this possible?

Comment: Unrelated but never use `valueForKey` unless you mean KVC (you don't).

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a predicate to search for hashtagged tags:

```
        // MARK: - Without Loop
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hashtag != NULL"];
        NSArray *hashtaggedTags = [tags filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if (hashtaggedTags.count == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No hashtags at all");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Found some hashtags");
        }
```

---

Cleaning up your code for a minimum workable code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Assuming you have some dictionary like this
        NSDictionary * Tags = @{
            @"data": @[ // <- Here is the array
                @{ // <- here is the dictionary
                    @"hashtag": @"NightOut",
                    @"count"  : @0,
                }
            ]
        };

        // Getting the tag value
        NSArray* tags = Tags[@"data"];

        // MARK: - Without Loop
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hashtag != NULL"];
        NSArray *hashtaggedTags = [tags filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if (hashtaggedTags.count == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No hashtags at all");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Found some hashtags");
        }

        // MARK: - With loop
        // Loop through tags (not keys of the dictionary)
        for (NSDictionary * tag in tags) {
            // Check if `hashtag` is exists and returns something in the dictionary or not
            if (tag[@"hashtag"]) {
                NSLog(@"There's an object set for key @\"hashtag\"!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No object set for key @\"hashtag\"");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i get *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000135bf00'

Comment: crashing on this line actually if (tag[@"hashtag"])

Comment: It seems like one of the dictionaries is actually an `NSArray` ! Please take a look at the fully working example, and post more about your `Tags` object if you did not understand your issue.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/tZXD18C6 please check the image i do not see any array...

Comment: That `@"3 elements"` tells that the data is an `NSArray`

Comment: I have added another method using predicate with the full sample code. Take a look

Comment: You were right NSArray* tags = Tags[@"data"]; worked it returned an array and not a nsdictionary. I am accepting your answer thanks so much Mr Mojtaba! I see that you are an instructor. Is there any way to teach me doing interfaces? I have a task like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfMfD4-hRCw but i am a junior developer in objective c and i do not know where to start :) I have sent you a request in linkedin :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242181/discussion-between-stefanosn-and-mojtaba-hosseini).